# Error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)

Tags: java-8

Tengo este metodo que en teoria deberia de ordenarme por nombre a los propietarios y listarlos, pero por alguna razon da ese error al llamar al metodo. Deputando he visto que el error ocurre en la linea Collection.sort

```
public static List consultarPropietarios(ObjectContainer db) {   

 Propietario propietario = new Propietario(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    ObjectSet res = db.queryByExample(propietario);  
    List<Propietario> a = res;
    Comparator<Propietario> compareByNom = (Propietario p1, Propietario p2) -> p1.getNombre().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getNombre());
    Collections.sort(a, compareByNom);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: pone la pregunta donde da el error en la linea de collectios lee antes de criticar. y Collectios.sort es el metodo de java 8 para comparar

Comment: Ah, cierto. Me retracto. No debí meterme en preguntas de Java, no es mi campo.